# ThingWorx Subscription code isn't getting executed on reaching an alert threshold limit

Tags: javascript, iot, thingworx

In `ThingWorx`, I've created an alert on a property, and it is getting triggered on reaching a threshold and is being notified in Alert monitoring section, but the subscription created by binding the same alert isn't getting executed. I've even added logger statements within the subscription code, but couldn't see it in the application logs.

Is there any restriction / limitation in `ThingWorx` trial version on subscriptions and alerts as such? ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no limitation/restriction to subscriptions or alerts in the ThingWorx trial version. In order to view logger statements, you must check the Script Log, not the Application log.

For more detailed information regarding subscriptions, see the ThingWorx 9 docs [here](https://support.ptc.com/help/thingworx/platform/r9/en/#page/ThingWorx/Help/Composer/Things/ThingSubscriptions/ThingSubscriptions.html#) and [here](https://support.ptc.com/help/thingworx/platform/r9/en/index.html#page/ThingWorx/Help/Best_Practices_for_Developing_Applications/EventsAlertsSubscriptions.html)

Answer (score -1):

No, but have the set the subscription to be active? There's a checkbox.

Comment: This is not an answer, but a comment.

Comment: Sure, @DanielMarín? Question was if there is a restriction. Answer is no. Willing to learn here.